# Documentation Topic Review and duplicate topics

Tags: feature-request, documentation, documentation-topics

I spent some time over two weeks ago writing a [nice detailed topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/hibernate/5742/hibernate-entity-relationships-using-annotations#t=201609010603448264442) in a fairly out of the way Documentation tag, containing sample code, diagrams and explanations on all the examples.

This <strike>hasn't been reviewed yet</strike> has now been reviewed, but because the tag is fairly small and once you've actually got a grip on how the library works, you don't really need the documentation any more.

The problem <strike>is</strike> was, because this submission still hadn't been reviewed, we were getting other users coming along and trying to create duplicate topics.  These can't be flagged as such because the original topic request hadn't been approved. There are currently 3 other topic suggestions that haven't been reviewed that provide far fewer examples and less explanation that essentially duplicate my suggestion.

For low traffic tags this is just producing noise when the limited eyeballs come through looking for things to review. I'm happy to put time into cleaning up the tag, but I feel like my options are limited when it comes to things like this. Can we get the ability to reject a topic suggestion being duplicated by another topic suggestion?

<sub>I'll provide the following links for [my suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/hibernate/5742/hibernate-entity-relationships-using-annotations#t=201609010603448264442) and [the](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/87750) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/81425) [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/62034) in case readers think I'm favouring my topic over others because I wrote it.</sub>

Comment: I understand there is a review queue coming, which should help things not get "stuck". Perhaps just lowering the review bar for low traffic tags might be a good alternative here? If there aren't people around to review things, expecting 4 votes might just discourage users.